# Linear algebra(Linear transform and matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

with condition
$T:V \rightarrow V$
$\tilde{A}$={A1, A2, A3, A4, A5}
$\tilde{B}$={A1, A1+A2, A1+A2+A3, A1+A2+A3+A4, A1+A2+A3+A4+A5}
$T(A_i)=A_{i+1}, i = 1, ..., 4$ 
$T(A5) = O$

(1) Get $(T)$$ \tilde{A} \over \tilde{A}$ 
(2) Get $(T)$$ \tilde{B} \over \tilde{B}$ 

I have no idea how to get the answers. Can I use standard basis to get the answers?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  One way to get $T$ rel two bases is to apply it to the elements of the first and then write the results in terms of the second.   So, to get you started, the first column of the first one is $T(A_1)=A_2$, which in terms of $\tilde A$ is $(0,1,0,0,0)$.  Etc...